# Powershell Script to Create TXT Files from folders

Tags: powershell

I received some excellent advice on how to create txt files based on the files in a folder using this PowerShell script.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\temp\" -Recurse -File |
Where-Object {$_.Extension -notin '.txt'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Users\temp\" + $_.BaseName + ".txt", $_.FullName)
}
```

How would I modify this script to create txt files based on folders only, and ignoring the files contained in those folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using a bit more PowerShell style and cmdlets would be:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\temp'
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory |
    Where-Object {$_.Extension -ne '.txt'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        Add-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + ".txt")) -Value $_.FullName
    }
```

p.s. I changed the `-notin` into `-ne` because that is more appropriate here since you are only comparing to a single string, not an array.

Comment: Again, fantastic! You are a lifesaver, Peter!

Comment: Well said @Theo .. But neat solution :)

Comment: Sorry, Theo. Thanks, Theo!

Answer (score 0):

In old PowerShell versions you would have to do a `| Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -re $true}`

but nowadays just replace your `-file` with `-directory`

Comment: Fantastic, Peter. Works like a charm. Thanks so much.

Is there a way to add a text string to the resulting TXT document, like "Cover Page"?